# How do Electrical Anomalies behave in Metro Exodus?

Tags: metro-exodus

Electrical Anomalies are an unusual danger in the Metro series and with the open world of Metro Exodus they make a reappearance as one of Russia's many threats.

What I know so far is that they're a form of ball lighting* and deal immense damage to Artyom.

What I've learned but I am not completely sure about is:

- Bullets and grenades do not seem to harm the anomalies
- Aim assist will still lock onto the lightning
- They are more prevalent at night
- They are more prevalent in areas with large amounts of metal such as the train yard in the VOLGA level
- They move slower than Artyom, but seem to constantly float towards him
- They will not pursue away from areas with high concentrations or metal
- They do not deal radiation damage

My specific questions are:

Are electrical anomalies an enemy or environmental hazard?

Is there any way to damage them or slow them down?

Are there any way to deal with them other than going around them?

Are they exhibit any other behaviors other than those listed above?

*Confirmed via in-game tape

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to your question, but in Metro 2033 (the first game in the trilogy), Anomalies are simply environmental hazards which you should just avoid.

Comment: All advice is appreciated. I've never played a Metro game so I'm trying to study it as much as I can. The wikia page for anomalies hasn't been very helpful

Comment: All anomalies I've seen have "expired" naturally by exploding (you may have to wait for some minutes). I also haven't seen any outside of the Volga map. I consider anomalies as a very minor aspect of the game, completely unlike the S.T.A.L.K.E.R. series.

Comment: Confirmed by Metro Wikia: they only appear in the VOLGA level.

Comment: In the original games, Khans explains that it reacts to movement. If you stop, it won't follow/attack you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw a tin can in their path which will cause them to stop, start discharging electricity and then reverse their course. Handy if caught in a bad spot with an anomaly bearing down on you.

Other than that you need to simply avoid them. They do not behave the same as the first two games, they will not just pass you by if you stand still.

In fact, it’s overheard on a tape in one of the safe houses that the electrical anomalies are drawn to “technology”. I’m assuming anything with batteries or an electrical current. That may explain why they are drawn to Artyom.